# Spring boot setup logging before spring application starts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project where I need the logging mechanism before I start the SpringApplication. How can I achieve that?

I tried to setup my own logging mechanism (LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration()), but it is overridden when the spring application starts.

Basically I want to use the same logging mechanism everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve my issue by removing "spring-boot-starter-logging" dependency from my project and adding 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.5' and 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1'.

I use gradle so in my case I achieve that by:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
}

compile('org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.5')
compile('commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1')
```

Removing LoggingApplicationListener and logback.xml didn't worked.

Answer (score 4):

Spring Boot uses `LoggingApplicationListener` to configure logging for your application. This listener is one of `SpringApplication`'s default listeners. To use your own already-configure logging system, you need to configure your `SpringApplication` so that it doesn't have this listener. For example, to remove the unwanted listener, while retaining all of the other default listeners:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CustomLoggingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication application = 
                new SpringApplication(CustomLoggingApplication.class);

        Collection<ApplicationListener<?>> listeners = 
                new ArrayList<ApplicationListener<?>>();
        for (ApplicationListener<?> listener: application.getListeners()) {
            if (!(listener instanceof LoggingApplicationListener)) {
                listeners.add(listener);
            }
        }
        application.setListeners(listeners);

        application.run(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Log4j listener in the web.xml instead of the spring-context.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

So it is up before Spring starts.

Comment: My project don't have a web.xml file, and i would prefer to not use it. I also have dependent project that use Java logging mechanism.