# Configure Spring logging piror to application context loading

Tags: spring, logging, logback, spring-logback

I have a CLI tool that is based on Spring framework (3.2.12) and using logback (1.23) for logging.

My problem is that the logging config does not take effect until the app cxt is loaded, thus polluting the command line with the logs of the init procedure.
Is there a way to force Spring to load and use the log configuration in the first place?

Main class:

```
public class MyCliMain {

private static final JcanLogger LOG = SessionLogFactory.getLog(MyCliMain.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int exitCode;
    ApplicationContext cxt = initApplicationContext();
    exitCode = cxt.getBean(CommandRunner.class).run(args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}

private static ApplicationContext initApplicationContext() {
    AbstractApplicationContext cxt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-pay-bus-cli-G8Q.xml");
    cxt.registerShutdownHook();
    return cxt;
}}
```

Logback config in resources:

```
<appender name="writeToConsole" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.out</target>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="writeToFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${log.output}</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-30(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{32} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="com..." level="DEBUG" appender-ref="writeToFile"/>
<logger name="com... level="DEBUG"/>

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="writeToConsole"/>
    <appender-ref ref="writeToFile" />
</root>
```

Console log out put:

```
Apr 01, 2021 4:07:23 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@7c16905e: startup date [Thu Apr 01 16:07:23 CEST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 01, 2021 4:07:23 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
...
logging config takes effect: 
WARN o.a.c.j.u.ResourceUtils - No resource methods have been found for resource class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient
WARN o.a.c.j.u.ResourceUtils - No resource methods have been found for resource class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient
WARN o.a.c.j.u.ResourceUtils - No resource methods have been found for resource class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient
INFO c.u.s.v.c.CommandRunner -
```

Comment: Please see if you find any usefull info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804769/spring-boot-setup-logging-before-spring-application-starts

Comment: @KajHejer Thanks, but that's for Spring Boot.